# relevant to the version in use as distinguished by the term ‘End User.’

Tags: meaning-in-context

> This Agreement is between you (either an individual or an entity) and A Software Products, (hereinafter called ‘A’) A is willing to grant you the following the rights to use the Software known as B PDF Editor and its accompanying documentation (collectively, the ‘Software’) only if you agree to be bound by all of the terms and conditions of this Agreement, **relevant to the version in use as distinguished by the term ‘End User.’**  If you are not willing to agree to any of the terms of this Agreement, A is unwilling to grant you a license and  ... you must delete it completely from any storage media you may have saved it to.

Please explain the clause in bold type. Does "version" refer to the software or the agreement? What would be the object governed by the verb "distinguished"?

Comment: "version *in use*" refers to the software. "as distinguished" also refers to the "version *in use*" (the End User distinguishes the version being used). There is no mention of more than the single "this" agreement.

Comment: I think that they have made a mistake. An agreement like this is normally called an "End User License Agreement" (EULA), and "End User" refers to "you". It shows how many people actually read this guff: even the person who wrote it could not be bothered to read and check it properly.

Comment: It's not clear, and I could only understand it by perhaps reading the entire agreement and inferring from context.  So this question isn't really about "learning English" as much as "identifying confusing English".

Comment: Seems like gibberish to me.

Comment: Maybe some term of that agreement, titled "End User" specify the version of software product agreement pertains to.

Answer (score 0):

> version in use

would be referring to the version of Software being used.  It is unclear if the agreement is referring to all of the versions, including updates which put be deleted or only the *current* version (last version) being used.